# MySQL trigger - insert into variably named table

Tags: mysql, triggers

Starting with a MySQL trigger like this:

```
delimiter #

create trigger comments_after_ins_trig after insert on comments
for each row
begin
  insert into comment_types (comment, user_id) values (new.comment, new.user_id);
end#
```

Let's say I wanted to split the inserts into different table, for instance if comment contains a vulgar word (`LOCATE('sh**', comment) > 0`), instead of comment_types I want to insert into a table called vulgar_comments, if the comment contains the words "thanks" or "nice" insert into nice_comments, etc.  Basically how do I make the table name to insert into variable for that trigger?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

Comment: I know about if, but I just can't go `insert into if(LOCATE('sh**', comment) > 0, "vulgar_comments", "comment_types") (comment, user_id) values (new.comment, new.user_id);`

Comment: How about adding a column to 'comment_types' that contains.. well.. the comment type? IE 1 = nice, 2 = not so nice, 3 = mean and so on.

Comment: That's how it was originally written, but there's now a need to separate them out. Unfortunately a VIEW is not possible either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one, I have tested this and this works on my end:

```
delimiter $$
drop trigger if exists `comments_after_ins_trig`$$
create trigger `comments_after_ins_trig` after insert on comments
for each row
begin
 if(locate("sh**", new.comment) > 0) then
   insert into vulgar_comments(comment, user_id) values (new.comment, new.user_id);
 else
   insert into comment_types (comment, user_id) values (new.comment, new.user_id);
 end if;
end$$

delimiter ;
```